# Shopware 6 Plugin: Issue with Generating SEO-Friendly URLs in Pagination for Search Results

Tags: twig, shopware, shopware6

I'm facing an issue with generating SEO-friendly URLs in Shopware 6 when implementing pagination for search results. I have a custom Twig template that extends the pagination.html.twig template from the storefront. The code works perfectly for generating SEO URLs in categories, but I'm encountering problems when navigating to page 2 (from page 1) from a search results page.

The issue seems to revolve around how I'm modifying the seoParams and handling the currentNavigationId for search result pages. Here's a simplified version of the code

```
{# Extend the 'pagination.html.twig' template from the storefront #}
{% sw_extends '@Storefront/storefront/component/pagination.html.twig' %}

{# Define the 'component_pagination' block #}
{% block component_pagination %}
        
        {# Loop through each page #}
        {% for i in 1..totalPages %}
            
            {# Set up an empty SEO parameters object #}
            {% set seoParams = {} %}
            
            {# Retrieve and modify query parameters #}
            {% set seoParams = context.context.extensions.tanmarNgSeoPagination.queryParameters %}
                        
            {# Check if the current page is not equal to the current iteration #}
            {% if i != currentPage %}
                {% if currentPage %}
                    {% set seoParams = seoParams|merge({ p: i }) %}
                {% endif %}
                
                {# Properly encode the SEO parameters into a string before using it #}
                {% set seoParams = '?' ~ seoParams|url_encode %}
                
                {# Check if currentNavigationId is defined and generate SEO-friendly URL #}
                {% if currentNavigationId is defined %}
                    {{ dump(seoParams) }}
                    <a href="{{ seoUrl('frontend.navigation.page', { navigationId: currentNavigationId }) ~ seoParams }}"></a>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    
    {# Call the parent pagination block #}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

I have checked the URL encoding, seoUrl function, and the overall logic, but I can't seem to figure out why the SEO URLs are not being generated correctly when navigating to page 2 from a search results page. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have noticed one thing. When I search for something the link of the browser changes such that it removes "/Clothing/Men/" from the link http://localhost/Clothing/Men/ and change it to http://localhost/search?search=new

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Any reason you're doing this all in a template?

Comment: @DarkBee I can not access all of my query parameters in the template **dynamically**. For instance, there might be some cases when certain shops have some custom filter property. In the template we can not access all the query parameters at once without giving their name `app.request.get('name')`.

Comment: Still unsure why you just don't use a Twig\Filter or Twig\Function

Comment: You could probably have done something like: `{% for key, value in app.request.query %}`. That's what I am doing, and it works in our case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search page uses a different route than the navigation pages. It also doesn't take a `navigationId` as a parameter, as it is not associated with one specific category for instance. You can check whether the page has a current `searchTerm` property and, if so, generate a URL for the correct `frontend.search.page` route name. While you do that, you can also add the `searchTerm` to the rest of your parameters, as you'll want further URLs in your pagination to continue using that search term.

```html
{% if page.searchTerm is defined %}
    {% set seoUrl = seoUrl('frontend.search.page') %}
    {% set seoParams = seoParams|merge({ search: page.searchTerm }) %}
{% else %}
    {% set seoUrl = seoUrl('frontend.navigation.page', { navigationId: currentNavigationId }) %}
{% endif %}
    
{% set seoParams = '?' ~ seoParams|url_encode %}
<a href="{{ seoUrl ~ seoParams }}"></a>
```